# Got invalid client secret, missing parameters client_secret, client_assertion when trying to get token in MS Azure

Tags: python, azure

My goal is to get token then querying graph resources.

I wrote these codes to get token from my app. First code, acquire token with login/pass:

```
from adal import AuthenticationContext

auth_context = AuthenticationContext('https://login.microsoftonline.com/g***************r.onmicrosoft.com')

token = auth_context.acquire_token_with_username_password('https://graph.microsoft.com',
                                                       't***************n.fr',
                                                       '***************', 'de8bc8b5-***************-b748da725064')
```

and got these :

> adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: e9ffa752-a258-4e32-9164-156e50912a00\r\nCorrelation ID: afb3c52f-8f36-4904-9926-90ba2aaba0ab\r\nTimestamp: 2020-12-08 14:02:58Z","error_codes":[7000218],"timestamp":"2020-12-08 14:02:58Z","trace_id":"e9ffa752-a258-4e32-9164-156e50912a00","correlation_id":"afb3c52f-8f36-4904-9926-90ba2aaba0ab","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218"}

Second code, acquire token with client credentials:

```
from adal import AuthenticationContext

auth_context = AuthenticationContext('https://login.microsoftonline.com/g*************r.onmicrosoft.com')

token = auth_context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials('https://graph.microsoft.com',
                                                       'de8bc8b5-************-b748da725064',
                                                       '****************************')
```

And got these:

> adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 79fe51c5-2987-4855-acf5-88fee0592a00\r\nCorrelation ID: cdfc9215-b7a6-4ceb-9d90-2de371c3178c\r\nTimestamp: 2020-12-08 14:21:13Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2020-12-08 14:21:13Z","trace_id":"79fe51c5-2987-4855-acf5-88fee0592a00","correlation_id":"cdfc9215-b7a6-4ceb-9d90-2de371c3178c","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}

I don't know if the client secret is wrong or something I did?

Comment: Don't provide links to your errors. Copy-paste them directly into the question. Links go bad over time, and your question should be fully contained in the post.

Comment: @Filmzy let me change that

Comment: COuld you please tell me how you register Azure AD application?

Comment: @Jim Xu I don't have hand in Azure AD bc it is in the customer side. If you could give me a link to set this up correctly and I will send the instruction to the Azure AD administrator.

Comment: @m0r7y Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-client-secret and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need those libs.
Lib requests was enough.

```
def authenticate_oauth():
    validation_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/******************.com/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    client_id = '1a******************************b7'
    client_secret = '-*****************************r'
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    params = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'grant_type': grant_type,
        'scope': scope,
    }
    response = requests.post(validation_url, data=params)

    return json.loads(response.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = authenticate_oauth()
    if 'access_token' in token:
        graph_data = requests.get(
        'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']})
        data_users = json.loads(graph_data.content)
        for data in data_users['value']:
            print(data)
```